# .Map Array inside Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I´m trying to filter the data but i have an array inside an array, and i have no idea how can i get those! Also there is a property called 'toString' and thats might be a problem (function)

```
        const filterteste = this.state.example.changelog.histories.map(item => (
        {
          id: item.id,            
          created: item.created,
          field: item.items.field,
          fromStringprop: item.items.fromString,
          toStringprop: item.items.toString,
        }
      ));
```

Desired Ouput:
I´m trying to filter the array soo i have a clean array with the properties i will need

```
{
   created: 
   id:
   field:
   fromString:
   toString:
}
```

**Problem:** 
[image]

Comment: You need to explain more specifically what you want to do. Filter what exactly? What is the expected output? Clarify a bit please.

Comment: In your `.map` handler, you can call `.map(item.items)` to map the child array, or any other Array method (do you maybe need something like `.reduce` or `.filter` for the child array?)

Comment: Hi @Chris ! I´m trying to have a clean array with the properties i need only!

Comment: How would you handle the author with id 56617 that seems to have an array of 2 items? How does that datastructure look like?

Comment: @Icepickle i´ve deleted Author property but its an object `Author {name:example, id: example}`, but i´m not going to need it!

Comment: could you provide a mock of your input data and an example of what you expect as result of that transformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply filter out them as

```
 const filterteste = this.state.example.changelog.histories.map(item => (
        {
          id: item.id,            
          created: item.created,
          field: item.items.field,
          fromStringprop: item.items.filter((item)=> return item.fromString != null),
          toStringprop: item.items.filter((item)=> return item.toString != null)
        }
      ));
```

Comment: would you please make sure that `item.items` is not stringify?

Answer (score 2):

```
const filterteste = this.state.example.changelog.histories.map(item => {
    //instead of returning a single item, we return an array!
    return item.items.map(childItem => {
        return {
            id: item.id,            
            created: item.created,
            field: childItem.field,
            fromStringprop: childItem.fromString,
            toStringprop: childItem.toString,
        };
    });
});
```

With this code you're mapping the base array elements, and each of these elements is returned as a map of the child elements - does this make sense?

After this you will still have an array, like so:

```
[
    [
        //item1,
        //item2
    ],
    [
        //item3
    ]
]
```

At this point we can just call `reduce` on this array to get to our expected result...

```
let resultOfArrayMap = theMapFunctionFromTopOfThePost(baseArray);
const properlyMappedArray = resultOfArrayMap.reduce((arrayBeingBuilt, currValue) => {
    return arrayBeingBuilt.concat(...currValue);
}, []);
```

This starts from an empty array, for each item in our mapped array it concats all of the child items in a new array, then proceeds to the next item and keeps contatenating other items to the array returned by processing the previous element...

It should now look like this:

```
[
    //item1,
    //item2,
    //item3
]
```